# Can ReSharper always jump to view's .cshtml in ASP.NET MVC project instead of asking me?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, resharper, go-to-definition

I'm talking about this menu, which appears when I press Ctrl+B:
[image]

In 99.99% I want to see a .cshtml, could it be made a default option (so that resharper would open the file without asking)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such possibility now. But you can file a request for it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is: there is no such feature in ReSharper yet (I posted an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-367794) and they added it to 8.1 backlog).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it comes with Visual Studio or ReSharper but there is a shortcut named Go to View.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Maybe not the answer you are looking for but it's quite useful.

Comment: Thanks! but it don't work when I'm returning a view with explicit name from controller (like here `return View("ViewName", new GridModel(query));`. It says "Unable to find matching view".

Comment: @vorou Yeah, it only tries to find the default view I guess.